# CRUD SP generator for SQL Server 2008 (R2)

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I am using SQL Server 2008 R2. Is there a free script/utility which can make CRUD SPs for all of my database tables? I use to have one but lost the script.

Thanks

Comment: I'd like to see an ONLINE one, so I can quickly generate a few fast procs. Paste a CREATE TABLE statement into a textbox and click a button, get a page with CREATE PROC statements that makes the CRUD procs. (I'm often at clients where doing things like downloading programs is prohibited - for good reasons, really.)

Answer (score 2):

I use [SSMS Tools Pack](http://www.ssmstoolspack.com/), a CRUD generator is only one of the many features it has that I use on a regular basis.  You can also customize the templates it uses to create the CRUD SPs.

Answer (score 0):

You could always use something like [MyGeneration](https://sourceforge.net/projects/mygeneration/).  It's free and can do a lot more than just crud operations.  If it doesn't have the templates you need you could always create them pretty easily.

Comment: I stumbled on this old thread. I think the indicated MyGeneration software is now on SourceForge, last updated in 2013 as of this moment. http://sourceforge.net/projects/mygeneration/