# Generate SQL for POCO objects?

Tags: c#, sql, poco

Is it possible using nHibernate, or Entity Framework, or whatever, to generate the SQL necessary to INSERT or UPDATE an object I've mapped to a table?  I'm looking at generating SQL scripts from these POCO classes instead of running directly against a database.

The idea here is I'm taking some 2000+ line SQL scripts and I've made a Python-based DSL that does a lot of the work for us.  I've got a C# application now that loads IronPython and 'compiles' the Python script, generating all of the necessary objects.  I've got a prototype script here that's roughly 100 lines.  Now, I need to actually generate the SQL script.

I could use something like nVelocity, but if this project is successful, I want to keep the long-term door open for running against a database.  I've got roughly 30 tables with a few dozen columns per table to script out.

I found this but it appears to be generating the database table schema, rather than writing inserts and updates:  https://forum.hibernate.org/viewtopic.php?f=25&t=1000334

The documentation on [SchemaExport](http://wiki.fluentnhibernate.org/Schema_generation) doesn't give a lot of information.

Suggestions / ideas?

Comment: I know it's an old question already. And there are many methods to achieve what you're looking for (most common one are ORMs), but ORMs aren't always the best solutions (many discussions about this subject online) - myself - I like micro-orms, but the biggest downside to them is that you have to write SQL queries on your own - to tackle this I've decided to write a library to generate SQL from poco objects (without touching or having to reference the library other from you DAL layer). would like to hear what you think: https://github.com/developer82/Poco.Sql

Answer (score 0):

I think it is not possible.It can generate the schema, but the sql for the crud is generated on the fly.

You can use tools that generates T-sql for doing the CRUD against a table.

Comment: What tools are you referring to?

Comment: you have it here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2037802/crud-sp-generator-for-sql-server-2008-r2